# Proper way to test Android app on lower API level (Android Studio)

Tags: android, compiler-errors, build.gradle

I am new to Android (but not new to programming) and developing my first serious Android app. Everything went fine until I was developing for Marshmallow (API level 23). I decided to test my app on another device with API level 16 and now compiler throws MANY warnings and errors like this:

```
06-26 12:14:13.060 19473-19473/com.blueit.unico E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-26 12:14:13.100 19473-19473/com.blueit.unico W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 482: Landroid/content/Context;.getSystemService (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
06-26 12:14:13.100 19473-19473/com.blueit.unico E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method com.blueit.unico.UnicoApplication.access$super
06-26 12:14:13.100 19473-19473/com.blueit.unico W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 242 (Landroid/os/UserHandle;) in Lcom/blueit/unico/UnicoApplication;
06-26 12:14:13.100 19473-19473/com.blueit.unico W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 536: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
```

Seems like some kind of version conflict. Application itself is deployed and *seems* to be working fine (but it is very basic now). I have done some research on the Internet and people mention that I need to change targetSDKVersion in build.gradle file. But do I really need to edit this file manually? Shouldn't Android Studio recognize that device has older API and compile for that version? I did some little test apps before and they run or different devices with no problems without changing anything. 
In case people on internet are right and I really need to edit build.gradle file by hand, it looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blueit.unico"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Then new questions arise. What exactly do I have to change? It is clear for me that targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion should probably be changed, but what about these lines?

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

Should they be changed too? And if yes, to what versions?
Thank you in advance.

**SOLVED:** After noticing that all errors and warnings come from `dalvikvm` and [doing](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/FAQs) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067886/vfy-unable-to-resolve-lots-of-stuff) research for several hours I came to conclusion that this is some kind of dalvik virtual machine verification and they are not "real" errors and warnings - just information that my app uses newer features (which it certainly does). Feels weird to ignore tens of errors and warnings though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to older devices, you can still download older images in the Android Stuido SDK and emulate the old devices.

Answer (score 0):

Install new emulators with lower android versions (you may want to try Genymotion). There is also support library, which port new features to lower apis (class names begin with support, see docs)

Comment: I have a physical device with API level 16, no need for emulators. Problem is with compiling. Maybe I should have rephrased subject..

Answer (score 0):

The Android Studio does indeed recognize which OS version is device trying to download the app. But the problem is your app probably doesn't target older versions, but only API 23. When you use API 23, there are some new classes that were added in API 23 that older versions can't run. So you need to make version of your app that targets older versions too and if there were some classes that you need and that are from API 23, you need to find a way to implement that differently.

Comment: He has min api version 11, I thought that meant gradle would check that all utilized api was compatible back to that version?

Comment: I was counting on Android Studio warning me when I use features incompatible with my minimum SDK version. But it did not this time. Why not? Some setting in IDE maybe?

Comment: Well API 11 is compatible with 100% devices I think. @Janeks Bergs check what is your targeted API and what is your minimum API. I think that may be the problem but I'm not sure. If your minimum API is 11 and targeted 23, AS won't warn you about that.

Comment: @leonz ok, I start to understand... so IDE warns me only when there are incompatibilities with targeted SDK, not the one which I am trying to deploy to, right?

Comment: I think so, yes. Altough don't take me for my word, but rather check it on Google Developers page. Also, always try to go as low as you can with API. If your targeted API is 23, but your app doesn't use any class higher of API 20, you should use API 20 then.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the target sdk version. The min sdk version defines the lowest api version that your app will support, and 11 is already very low. The target sdk version is the version that the app is compiled against, and the min sdk version is simply telling android studio to not let you use feature that aren't available before that version - unless you handle it explicitly. Also, you definitely don't need to change the app compat library versions - they are there to make the latest api's available for older versions. You mentioned that your application is working fine - if that is correct, then you don't need to do anything!

Comment: It works fine but do I understand correctly, that whenever the "new" features happen to be used, there will be a crash? How do I guarantee that this is not gonna happen?

Comment: You understand correctly, except it will 'crash' when you try to build the project in android studio (so it won't even let you create an apk that uses newer features than you said you would as your min sdk). As a side note, the min sdk is literally the min sdk. You couldn't  even install an app with min sdk 11 on a device that was sdk 10.

Comment: I am still confused. So Android Studio lets me BUILD the apk and deploy it to device even if it knows that app uses features available only in newer SDKs? But that's a recipe for crashes!

Comment: Other way round. It only lets you build if it knows your app DOESN'T use features that aren't available in the min sdk version.

Comment: As you can see it does. Problems and error messages start only when app is deployed on device.

Comment: Looks like problem is "solved". Look at original post. Errors and warnings did not go away, but the source is Dalvik verification. No need to change SDK versions.